# WooCommerce Cart - Dynamic Price variable pass into custom price hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am getting the dynamic custom price in a variable that I want to pass to the hooked function in **woocommerce_before_calculate_totals** hook in cart. But it isn't working.

This is my code:

```
  $add=200; //I want to pass this variable in add_action hook
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_total_price');
  function add_custom_total_price($cart_object) {
     global $woocommerce;
     $custom_price =$add; // This is my custom price
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
       $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
 }
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: i have tried your answer is working fine.. right now i am not using this method.i was using variation..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912552/how-to-show-the-radio-buttons-and-dropdown-woocommerce-variations?noredirect=1#comment65369036_38912552  please suggest me this question woocommerce.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work you just need to define **`$custom_price`** variables as global in your function, this way:

```
$custom_price = 200; 

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_item_price', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_item_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    global $custom_price;

    foreach (  $cart_object->get_cart() as $item_values ) {
        $item_values['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

**This code is tested and working** *(for woocommerce versions 2.5+ and 2.6+)*.

*Naturally this code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme.*

Answer (score 0):

To add Price in your woocommerce cart before calculate total -

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_total_price');

  function add_custom_total_price($cart_object) {
     global $woocommerce,$add,$custom_price; 
     $add=200;//Dynamic Price variable
     $custom_price =$add;//Dynamic Price variable pass to custom price
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
       $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
 }
```