# Using radio buttons and drop down selector at the same time for product variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am using the product variation like **`Height`**, **`Weight`** and **`Thickness`**. Before that, all the variation attributes were displaying in drop-down selectors.

But now I am using [woocommerce-radio-buttons plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/woocommerce-radio-buttons). This plugin converts the drop-down into a radio button. I want to convert only the radio button for **`Height`** and **`Weight`**.

But I don't want **`Thickness`** as a radio button, because I need it as a drop-down selector.

How to do that?

Comment: Now I am not using the custom price. i was using the variable products for the variation price. that why i have not tried for your previous question answer... please suggest me this question any other way is there. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..