# WooCommerce - Adding a custom price to each product in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I would like to update the price of products adding a custom price in cart using this simple piece of code `update_post_meta( $product->id, '_regular_price', $frame_price_added);`.

**Note:** what I'm trying to achieve is to add this custom price to each product in cart.

I have try to get `$frame_price_added` this way:

```
$frame_price = $res['_number_field'][0];
$frame_price_added = $product->price + $frame_price;
```

Here `$product->price` is price coming from woocomerce product and `$frame_price` is coming from my newly added price.

I was wondering how do I associate this new price to cart, because it doesn't work.

I have tried using `update_post_meta( $product->id, '_price', $frame_price_added);` and when page is refreshed it adds and stores the custom price to the product, and saved it.

Any idea on how I can achieve this properly?

Thanks.

---

> **Edit:** One more thing… I have searched a function that can being called on add to cart and i didn't find any thing, and also an action hook being called on `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` which had `woocommerce_single_product_summary` but it didn't find any function.

Comment: WooCommerce compares the `_regular_price` to the `sale_price` and the sale price's sale dates to determine the `_price` key. The `_price` is then the price that users will pay. Best that I can tell, it sounds like you may want to consider [Product Addons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/).

Comment: @helgatheviking ohh i have been reading all you comments on wordpress form -_- and i read that same as well :p sorry for asking that again but i was searching a way if we update actual price it's rightly served in cart.
So what i am thinking is to add a hook and update those prices in that hook after checkout destroy them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Update:** For WooCommerce 3.0+  [Change cart item prices in WooCommerce version 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324605/change-cart-item-prices-in-woocommerce-version-3-0/43327167#43327167)

You can use **`woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`** hook to customize your cart items prices.

You can define **`$framed_price`** variables as global in your function, this way.

This is the code:

```
// getting your additional price outside the function (making any conditional calculations) 
$framed_price = 20;

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_total_price', 10 );
function add_custom_total_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    global $framed_price;

    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price += $framed_price;
    }
}
```

Or get your custom price inside the hooked function *(optionally, depending on how you get your custom price)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_total_price', 10 );
function add_custom_total_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $framed_price = 20;

    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price += $framed_price;
    }
}
```

**This code is tested and working.**

*Naturally this code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or in any plugin file.*

Reference: [WooCommerce Cart - Dynamic Price variable pass into custom price hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716052/woocommerce-cart-dynamic-price-variable-pass-into-custom-price-hook/38755377#38755377)

Comment: how i can get the $framed_price  from my form ? i don't want it to be static

Comment: @sona what do you exactly mean/want? what form, what field?