# Add custom Product data dynamically as item meta data on the Order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, orders

Is it possible to add a metadata on a product which is inside the Order?

In this case, there would be one metadata but each product (in the order) would have different value.
Example:

```
Order 1:
     * Product 1 
     Sample Meta: Meta1

     * Product 2
     Sample Meta: Meta2
```

Thanks.

---

**Update1 :**

I'm now stuck on how would I grab the values from the `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` filter. I was able to successfully add the meta data from there.

I need to grab those values for me to use in this `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` action hook.

This is how I successfully added the metadata to the filter:

```
function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    $cart_item_data[ "meta1" ] = $_POST["meta1"];  
    $cart_item_data[ "meta2" ] = $_POST["meta2"]; 
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 99, 2 );
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes this is possible using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_add_order_item_meta`** action hook.

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','adding_custom_data_in_order_items_meta', 1, 1 );
function adding_custom_data_in_order_items_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

    // The corresponding Product Id for the item:
    $product_id = $values[ 'product_id' ];

    $custom_meta_value = $values['my_custom_field1_key'];
    // or $custom_meta_value = $_POST['my_custom_field_key'];
    // or $custom_meta_value = get_post_meta( $values[ 'product_id' ], '_some_meta_key', true );

    if ( !empty($custom_meta_value) ) 
        wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'custom_meta_key', $custom_meta_value, true);

    // And so on …
}
```

> But as your question is not detailed and you are not showing any code related to how this custom data is set in your products or passed to the cart object, is not possible to help more that that.

---

**Update related to your answer:** *(See in the linked answer with a working real example)*:

[Adding user custom field value to order items details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981493/adding-user-custom-field-value-to-order-items-details/41988701#41988701)

> So, as in this linked answer, **you will need to create first a product attribute** because in your code, `wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'The Meta', $the_meta );` is not correct as the second argument has to be a **`meta_key` slug** without **uppercase** and **space** characters, so `'The Meta'` is not convenient and not recommended...

This product attribute creation name will be (regarding your answer code): **`'The Meta'`** and the slug **`'the_meta'`**.

Then you will have to set it in each related product with a mandatory value *(just any value, as this value is going to be replaced by your custom value below)*.

So once done, your code will be:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','adding_custom_data_in_order_items_meta', 10, 3 );
function adding_custom_data_in_order_items_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( isset($values['meta1']) && isset($values['meta2']) ) {
        $custom_value = $values['meta1'] . '.' .  $values['meta2'];
        wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'pa_the-meta', $custom_value );
    }
}
```

Then you will get this kind of display in your Orders items ('XXXX' is your custom value here):

```
The Meta: XXXX
```

Comment: okie..i have deleted answer..but i think i had used 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed' for add order meta to order in past so posted my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link @LoicTheAztec. I added the attribute the product and changed "The Meta" to "the-meta"

Comment: perfect answer @LoicTheAztec, exactly what I'm looking for. thanks!

Comment: if ( !empty($custom field1) )  shouldn't be without '1'?

Answer (score 0):

After creating attribute "The Meta" and adding it to the product.

I answered my problem with the following:

**First**: Add the meta via `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` filter hook. This would add first the meta to the items inside the cart.

```
function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    $cart_item_data[ "meta1" ] = $_POST["meta1"];  
    $cart_item_data[ "meta2"] = $_POST["meta2"]; 
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
```

**Second**: Save the meta added to the cart to the actual items purchased within the order

```
function adding_custom_data_in_order_items_meta( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( isset($values['meta1']) && isset($values['meta2']) ) {
        $the_meta = $values['meta1'] . '.' .  $values['meta2'];
        wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'pa-the-meta', $the_meta );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','adding_custom_data_in_order_items_meta', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: My answer was correct with the provided information of your question at the beginning. In your code,` wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'The Meta', $the_meta );` is not correct as the second argument has to be a **`meta_key` slug** without uppercase and space characters, so your `'The Meta'` is not convenient and not recommended... **Look to my updated answer and you will see on the linked answer, how you can have a clean label displayed with that custom values…**

Comment: @thanks LoicTheAzted. I just changed the last parmeter from 1 to 3, as it should accept 3 parameters.

And about "The Meta", I've also thought about it. but if I make it a slug, It would be displayed as it is in the order details section. That's why I just decided to make it "The Meta" instead of "the_meta". Do you have any workaround on this? Thanks again

Comment: Your correct parameter has to be instead **`pa_the-meta`** see explanations in my linked answer.