# WooCommerce - Increase prices of simple and variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I would like to increase all product prices by some percentage in WooCommerce.

May be using a hook (example: regular price 100$ + 10%= 110$ ) **for simple and variable products**.

I would like to increase all simple and variable products price to extra 10% of the regular price.

How can I increase prices?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**THERE IS 2 CASES**

**CASE 1 - all products *(Bulk increase products prices by a percentage)***

> This custom function will update all products prices by a percentage that you **can set at the end of this code snippet**. This will be done **only one time**.
>
> **All the product prices, regular prices and sale price will be updated…**
>
> If you need to do it another time later on, see after this snippet code (below), the procedure.
>
> **This script will work only for logged admin users.**

```
function bulk_update_product_prices($percent=0){
    if(get_option( 'wc_bulk_updated_prices' ) != 'yes' && is_admin() ) {

        // prevent updating prices more than once
        add_option( 'wc_bulk_updated_prices' );

        $args = array(
            // WC product post types
            'post_type'   => array('product', 'product_variation'),
            // all posts
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        if($percent == 0) return;
        echo 'bla bla';
        $percent = 1 . '.' . $percent;
        $shop_products = get_posts( $args );
       foreach( $shop_products as $item){
            $meta_data = get_post_meta($item->ID);
            if (!empty($meta_data['_regular_price'])) {
                $regular_price = $meta_data['_regular_price'][0] * $percent;
                update_post_meta($item->ID, '_regular_price', $regular_price);
            }
            if (!empty($meta_data['_sale_price'])) {
                $sale_price = $meta_data['_sale_price'][0] * $percent;
                update_post_meta($item->ID, '_sale_price', $sale_price);
            }
            if (!empty($meta_data['_price'])) {
                $price = $meta_data['_price'][0] * $percent;
                update_post_meta($item->ID, '_price', $price);
            }
        }
        // Once done an option is set to yes to prevent multiple updates.
        update_option( 'wc_bulk_updated_prices', 'yes');
    }
}

// set your percentage (if you want 20%, so you put 20)
bulk_update_product_prices(20); // <== == == == == == Here set your percent value
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or in any plugin file.*

> NOW, browse a page of your web site (logged as admin). you are done.

**After that** you can remove this code.

---

**If you need to use this script once again, you will need to do this 4 steps. in the code snippet above:**

> **Step 1 - Reseting security option** - Replace this:
>
> ```
> // set your percentage (here the percentage is 20%, so we put 20)
> bulk_update_product_prices(20);
> ```
>
> By this:
>
> ```
> // Do it again later (Resetting the script)
> update_option( 'wc_bulk_updated_prices', 'no');
> ```
>
> **Step 2** - browse a page of your web site (logged as admin):
>
> **Step 3** - Replace back this:
>
> ```
> // Do it again later (Resetting the script)
> update_option( 'wc_bulk_updated_prices', 'no');
> ```
>
> By this:
>
> ```
> // set your percentage (here the percentage is 20%, so we put 20)
> bulk_update_product_prices(20);
> ```
>
> **Step 4 - **Update prices** - browse a page of your web site (logged as admin)

This code is tested and works.

---

**CASE 2 - Cart (Increasing cart items price)**

You can use **`woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`** hook to customize your cart items prices. 
Here in the code below, I add 10% to each items in cart.

This works for all kinds of product types.

This is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_percentage', 10 );
function add_custom_percentage( $cart_object ) {
    // set your percent (here 10 is 10%)
    $percent = 10;

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $item ) {
        $item['data']->price *= 1 . '.' . $percent;
    }
}
```

**This code is tested and working.**

*Naturally this code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or in any plugin file.*

References:

- [WooCommerce Cart - Dynamic Price variable pass into custom price hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716052/woocommerce-cart-dynamic-price-variable-pass-into-custom-price-hook/38755377#38755377)
- [WooCommerce - Adding a custom price to each product in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256362/woocommerce-adding-a-custom-price-to-each-product-in-cart/39256606#39256606)